# Spring boot favicon behavior with file upload

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have add favicon.ico  to my spring boot project it worked ok but when i added file upload services to my app it works ok but an expectation appear on the console knowing that the favicon.icon is in resources /static /favicon.ico

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: uploads\favicon.ico (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot, place all those resources under:

> /src/main/resources/public

Dont use static